# How to restrict Orchard search to blog posts (or any content type whatsoever)?

Tags: orchardcms

Orchard's built in search module will search (and index) everything on the site. What is the best way to restrict indexing/search (or search results) to specific content types? (Actually I need to restrict it to blog posts only).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't index the other types. There is a "index this content type for search" checkbox in the content type editor.

Comment: Is it possible to have a different index for admin search ?

Comment: Wow, this also solved the problem of the 1.7 index not getting my custom fields from my module: the checkbox on the content type wasn't checked.

Comment: @Bertrand Le Roy  Can we also create a 2nd search index for a special group of members who have access to special pages and files? If so, where can learn to build this?

Comment: You can create another index, yes. See http://docs.orchardproject.net/en/latest/Documentation/Search-and-indexing/ You can then restrict the permissions on the projections using that index using the user permissions module.